# js поиск на странице

Tags: javascript, css3, веб-программирование, html5

Всем привет, по ссылке ниже есть скрипт для поиска по странице, но проблема в том, что он начинает искать сразу после ввода в текстовое поле, а когда нажимаешь на стрелки соответсвенно переходит ко второму уже пункту, мне надо, что-бы он искал только после нажатия на "вперед", "назад"

Казалось бы простой скрипт, но я уже не могу понять, что я делаю не так, тело функции переносил из обработчика события в обработчик нажатия на кнопку, результата нет.

https://damonlsd.ru/jquery-poisk-i-podsvetka-teksta/

Сам скрипт:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var search_number = 0;
  var search_count = 0;
  var count_text = 0;
  var srch_numb = 0;

  function scroll_to_word() {
    var pos = $('body .selectHighlight').position();
    jQuery.scrollTo(".selectHighlight", 500, {
      offset: -150
    });
  }

  $('#search_text').bind('keyup oncnange', function() {
    $('body').removeHighlight();
    txt = $('#search_text').val();
    if (txt == '') return;

    $('body').highlight(txt);
    search_count = $('body span.highlight').length - 1;
    count_text = search_count + 1;
    search_number = 0;
    //$('body').selectHighlight(search_number);
    if (search_count >= 0) scroll_to_word();
    $('#count').html('Найдено: <b>' + count_text + '</b>');
    $('ul').removeClass('ng-scope ng-hide');
    $('ul').addClass('ng-scope');
    //  $('#search_block').css("z-index", "50");
    // $("#search_block").css("position", "fixed");
    // $("#search_block").css("background-color", "#dddddd");
    // $("#search_block").css("padding", "15px");
    //  $("#search_block").css("border-radius","6px");
    // $("#search_block").css("opacity", "0.9");
  });

  $('#clear_button').click(function() {
    $('body').removeHighlight();
    $('#search_text').val('');
    $('#count').html('');
    jQuery.scrollTo(0, 500, {
      queue: true
    });
    $('#search_block').css("z-index", "0");
    $("#search_block").css("position", "relative");
    $("#search_block").css("background-color", "#f3f3f3");
    $("#search_block").css("padding", "0px");
    $("#search_block").css("border-radius", "0px");
    $("#search_block").css("opacity", "1");
    // $('ul').removeClass('ng-scope');
    // $('ul').addClass('ng-scope ng-hide');
  });

  $('#prev_search').click(function() {
    if (search_number == 0) return;
    $('body .selectHighlight').removeClass('selectHighlight');
    search_number--;
    srch_numb = search_number + 1;
    $('body').selectHighlight(search_number);
    if (search_count >= 0) {
      scroll_to_word();
      $('#count').html(srch_numb + '</b> из ' + $('body span.highlight').length);
    }
  });

  $('#next_search').click(function() {
    var marker = 0;
    if (marker == 0) {
      $('#search_block').css("z-index", "50");
      $("#search_block").css("position", "fixed");
      $("#search_block").css("background-color", "#dddddd");
      $("#search_block").css("padding", "15px");
      $("#search_block").css("border-radius", "6px");
      $("#search_block").css("opacity", "0.9");
      marker = 1;
    }
    if (search_number == search_count) return;
    $('body .selectHighlight').removeClass('selectHighlight');
    search_number++;
    srch_numb = search_number + 1;
    $('body').selectHighlight(search_number);
    if (search_count >= 0) {
      scroll_to_word();
      $('#count').html(+srch_numb + '</b> из ' + $('body span.highlight').length);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Добавьте еще html-код, чтобы был работоспособный пример.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#search_text').bind('keyup oncnange', function() {
    $('body').removeHighlight();
    txt = $('#search_text').val();
    if (txt == '') return;

    $('body').highlight(txt);
    search_count = $('body span.highlight').length - 1;
    count_text = search_count + 1;
    search_number = 0;
    //$('body').selectHighlight(search_number);

    // ЗАКОММЕНТИРУЙТЕ
    // if (search_count >= 0) scroll_to_word();

    $('#count').html('Найдено: <b>' + count_text + '</b>');
    $('ul').removeClass('ng-scope ng-hide');
    $('ul').addClass('ng-scope');
    //  $('#search_block').css("z-index", "50");
    //  $("#search_block").css("position", "fixed");
    //  $("#search_block").css("background-color", "#dddddd");
    //  $("#search_block").css("padding", "15px");
    //      $("#search_block").css("border-radius","6px");
    //  $("#search_block").css("opacity", "0.9");
  });
```

Comment: спасибо) я тоже так делал, только проблема в том, что он переходит сразу ко второму тегу span :) т.е. начинает поиск со 2 пункта =(

Comment: Значит приводите в пример ни только скрипт. Но и HTML код, чтобы они исполнялись на этой странице.

Comment: т.е. скроллит страницу до 2 span'a 
работает так, после того как ввел слово, он  сразу скролит страницу с первому совпадени.
закоментируем скролл, страница не прокручивается, но либо переменная принимает в это время новое значение (увеличивается на 1 ) либо происходит что-то еще)

код то маленький, а никак понять не могу ЧЯДНТ

кстати паралельно подключены вда плагины highlightjs и js skrollTO